# I want to group by in excel

Tags: excel

[image: data have]
[image: Expected]

I want to group data in excel from left image to have result like right image.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you tried index() with match() ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this really easy with Consolidate Data:

> [Consolidate data in multiple
> worksheets](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/consolidate-data-in-multiple-worksheets-007ce8f4-2fae-4fea-9ee5-a0b2c9e36d9b)

[image]